# combination "+" with "$" in regex

Tags: regex

Thanks to everyone who has replied.
I think I have to tweak my first question a little bit.
I'm a little bit confusing because of the definition of $ sign.
It just asserts that there are between 6 and 10 word chars at the very end of the string.
That's it! Right? Then, It has to be matched with my test string `"123a56A781231231231241"` in my opinion. Because it doesn't break the rule!  **6-10 word chars at the very beginning of string, and at the very end of string. Perfect, isn't it?**

Plus, I want to know the difference between `^(?=\w{6,10}$)` and `^(?=\w{6,10})$`.

One more, *Casimir et Hippolyte* you said **The + doesn't change anything, this means only that the quantifier ( {6,10} here) is possessive and doesn't allow backtracks.** 
Is that means + sign makes $ sign disable?

Thank you guys in advance.

Before I go any further, I want you guys to know that it's been only 2 days since I started to study about regex. I'm totally newbie.

First. `^(?=\w{6,10}$)` This is pattern. Why the dollar signal has to be inside of `()` ? I know it's a dumb question but I'm curious. I tried to locate the dollar sign at the outside of `()`. But it didn't work as I expected.

Second. I found several tutorial site and it says the dollar sign means

> "`$` may appear at the end of a pattern to require the match to occur at the very end of a line. For example, `abc$` matches `123abc` but not `abc123.`"

So `$` is used to assert that the matched part of string is at the very end of a line. Right?

If that is true, why this pattern : `"^(?=\w{6,10}$)"` can't be matched with my test string : `"123a56A781231231231241"`.

As you see, my test string contains 6~10 word characters at the very beginning of a line and 6~10 word characters at the very end of a line.

Third. As I mention earlier, this pattern : `^(?=\w{6,10}$)` can't be matched with my test string : `"123a56A781231231231241"` But! if I add `+` sign behind of `\w{6,10}` like `^(?=\w{6,10}+$)`
it works. 
Is it because `+` sign is possessive? I mean,as far as I know, + sign tells the engine not to backtrack once a match has been made. So I hazard the guess, the $ sign doesn't do his job as it doesn't even do backtracking(I'm not sure about this,of course,as I don't know how the $ sign works behind). Is it right?

Comment: _it didn't work as I expected._ What does that mean? What did it do vs what did you expect it to do?

Comment: You should check this site out: http://www.debuggex.com/ It allows you to visualize what is happening with your expressions. Very cool site.

Comment: I tested with perl and `^(?=\w{6,10}+$)` doesn't work with the string  `123a56A781231231231241` (which makes sense since `+` is possessive)

Comment: Any reason you use `(?=...)`? It's 20 years since I use regexes, and I rarely found the need for lookaheads. So, I doubt that you really need it after just 2 days.

Comment: I've never said that I have to use `(?--...)`. Like I said I'm just trying to learn these things so I asked about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(?=..)` is a lookahead, it's a zero-width assertion, this means that it is just a check and matches **nothing**. In other word a lookahead means *followed by*.

The pattern `^(?=\w{6,10}$)` means:

*begining of the string followed by between 6 and 10 word characters until the end of the string.*

Note that there isn't any character matched since all is inside a lookahead exêct the ^ that is zero-width too.

A match function can only return an empty string as match result, but will return true if the condition is  met (otherwhise false)

The + doesn't change anything, this means only that the quantifier ( `{6,10}` here) is possessive and doesn't allow backtracks. More informations about this feature here: [www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

Comment: Thanks for your replying. I've got a question,though. You said `The + doesn't change anything, this means only that the quantifier ( {6,10} here) is possessive and doesn't allow backtracks.` Is that means + sign makes $ sign disable?

Comment: @user2528192: no it doesn't, the `+` after an other quantifier made it possessive, that only means that the regex can't backtrack into the group of character (`\w` here) when it fails. It is not very important here. See the link for more informations.

Answer (score 3):

If that's your whole regex, you don't need a look-ahead. ie these two regexes are equivalent:

```
^(?=\w{6,10}$)
^\w{6,10}$
```

Why the `$` needs to be inside the bracket? That's because the (anchored) look ahead ^(?=\w{6,10}) just asserts that there are between 6 and 10 word chars at the front of the input. But it will succeed if there's *more than* 6-10 word chars at the front of the input.

By putting the `$` inside the look ahead, it will only succeed if there are 6-10 word chars in the *whole* input.

You would only use a look ahead if you also wanted to have *another* restriction. For example, to match

> 6-10 word chars, and "a" appears before "b"

you would use the regex:

```
^(?=\w{6,10}$).*a.*b
```

Answer (score 2):

1. I can't help you with this because I don't know what you mean. Are you trying to match against the test string in **2** and **3**?
2. `^(?=\w{6,10}$)` is trying to match the beginning of the string, followed by 6-10 word characters and the end of the string. Your string is longer than 10 characters, so that won't match.
3. <s>When you add the `+` it matches **one or more** instances of the 6-10 character string.</s>

   Adding the `+` should still not match, because either way you are looking to match a string exactly 6-10 chars long, but your test string is longer. Making it possessive won't change the match in this instance.

Comment: `+` doesn't means "one or more instances" here. It's a possessive quantifier. More informations here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html